# Is it possible to use run-jetty-run's eclipse plugin to debug this app?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, jetty, arguments

Theres about 20 diff ant files, that make up the build. Im not sure how to configure run-jetty-runs eclipse plugin to use this information. Can anyone point me towards a tutorial or some documentation:

```
<target name="run-jetty" depends="build" description="Runs application in included Jetty container">
    <property file="credentials.properties" />
    <property name="jetty.port" value="8080" />
    <java jar="${jetty.dir}/start.jar" fork="true" dir="${basedir}" maxmemory="512M">
        <arg value="${jetty.conf.dir}/jetty.xml" />
        <arg value="${jetty.conf.dir}/jetty-jndi.xml" />
        <sysproperty key="jetty.port" value="${jetty.port}" />
        <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djetty.home=${jetty.dir}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djetty.datasource.lanter.username=${jetty.datasource.lanter.username}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djetty.datasource.lanter.password=${jetty.datasource.lanter.password}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djetty.datasource.vs.username=${jetty.datasource.us.username}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djetty.datasource.vs.password=${jetty.datasource.us.password}" />
        <jvmarg value="-DSTOP.PORT=${jetty.stop.port}" />
        <jvmarg value="-DSTOP.KEY=${jetty.stop.key}" />
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Start the app using the run-jetty-run plugin; this will give you an entry in the debug menu which means that Jetty (and the app) will be launched in the debugger if you select it.
2. Use the information in the code block above to create your own run configuration. The classpath should already be correct; you just need to select the correct main class (open `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in `start.jar` to find that out). Replace all the properties with their values and put each into a new line into the argument text fields of the run configuration.

On the tab "Common", you can set a file name and save the launch config as a file in your project, so everyone working on it will get it.